# How to write an extension method that can return different types for the same input?

Tags: c#

I want to write something like this:

```
    public static Int16 Parse(this byte[] buffer, int index)
    {
        var v = buffer[index++] << 8;
        v += buffer[index++];
        return (Int16)v;
    }

    public static Int32 Parse(this byte[] buffer, int index)
    {
        var v = buffer[index++] << 24;
        v += buffer[index++] << 16;
        v += buffer[index++] << 8;
        v += buffer[index++];
        return (Int16)v;
    }
```

But this isn't valid. I thought I could use generics:

```
    public static Int16 <Int16>Parse(this byte[] buffer, int index)
    {
        var v = buffer[index++] << 8;
        v += buffer[index++];
        return (Int16)v;
    }
```

But this does weird things:

- As written, VS says "redundant cast" and asks me to remove it
- If I remove the cast it says "cannot implicitly convert int to Int32"

Is there a way to do what I want with explicit generic parameters?

In a perfect world I would add extensions to `Int16` and `Int32` but extension methods have to be called on object instances, not called like `Int32.Parse()`

Comment: The usual solution here is to call them `ParseInt16` and `ParseInt32`, since C# doesn't allow overloading by return type

Comment: To answer the question, no you can't overload methods just by the return type. And since the methods aren't "generic" then using different names is the proper solution.

Comment: random question: why does the second version cast down to `short` (discarding half the values it just populated); should that just be `return v` ?

Comment: @DStanley I was under the impression you could treat the type as part of the name e.g. `buffer.Parse<Int16>(index)` but that might just be plain wrong, or something I'm mixing with C++.

Comment: @Mr.Boy You _can_, but you have diferent code depending on the type, so the method isn't "generic".  Since you have to specify the generic parameter depending on the return type you might as well just use different method names. IOW you'd have  `var x = ParseInt16(y,z);` versus `var x = Parse<Int16>(y,z);`

Comment: Also, you can't constrain a generic type to a numeric type (much less one in the `int` family), so you'd have to deal with that as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do what I want with explicit generic parameters?

No.

I mean, you could declare the method as `T Parse<T>(this byte[] buffer, int index)`, which would solve the return value issue. But, in the method you'd still have the problem of handling the input generically. You'd need to inspect `T` just to figure out how many bytes to "parse" (and you're not really parsing…it's more of a byte-conversion/reinterpret cast operation, whereas "parse" typically refers to converting text to data).

You'll do much better to just follow the examples of the `Convert`, `BitConverter`, and `BinaryReader` classes, which include the type name in the method name itself. You need different implementations for each method anyway, and you know you need to specify the type name explicitly anyway, so just keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution here is simply to use different names - usually a suffix based on the type.

In this **specific** case, your methods are redundant - there are framework methods for this, at least in some frameworks; you're essentially re-implementing:

- `BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt16BigEndian(...)`
- `BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian(...)`

(there is a *slight* difference re how the offset is specified; in the `BinaryPrimitives` version using spans, the offset is achieved via `Slice`)

Comment: In the specific case I suppose I might argue I want Endian-nes to be a parameter but I think you're probably right. I found that out in my other question after I'd already figured this was a question worth asking anyway for pure language knowledge

Comment: I think you mean `Span` not `Slice` though?

Comment: @Mr.Boy I mean both; once you have a *span* (and an array is fine as a span), you *slice* it to apply things like offsets and limits; your `index` usage is the equivalent of `someSpan.Slice(index)` with `BinaryPrimitives`

Comment: OK thanks - I was just going off the docs, I never used `Span` before (or knew it existed)